# How to make a TextView clickable but not to launch with the phone's browser

Tags: android, html

I am creating an Android Browser and within my browser i am making a Favorites page.
  In my favorite page, i have an EditText, where i insert the adress of the website i want to add, a remove button which removes all favorites and a TextView where the added websites are displayed.

My question is ...how can i make the adresses displayed in the TextView to be links, not only strings, BUT to be opened inside my browser?

All my tries so far ended up opening it with the phone's browser. My browser is structured like this: A menu, which is an OnListItemClick, where i can select HomePage, which has the main thing where you can browse the internet, with back and forward, refresh buttons. 
  In the menu, after the HomePage, i have Favorites, History and Settings. I need it to start the HomePage and to acces the site when i click the link from the favorites TextView. Can anyone give me an idea how to do it? I am sure i need to make a huge method for that, but I don't know how to start.

Comment: It would be nice if you could reformat your question to add some spaces and also make your question in a separate paragraph. In this way your question will attract more people :)

Comment: Why can't you have the favourites in a list view?

Comment: because it's easier in a text view...

Answer (score 0):

Know this is pretty late.  Just think others might also find this useful.

You can implement your own `ClickableSpan` to achieve that.  You can create a Spannable from scratch and assign to `TextView` like:

```
Spannable text = Spannable.newSpannable("Source text with link");
ClickableSpan link = new ClickableSpan {
    public abstract void onClick (View widget) {
        // Implement your own link behaviour
    }
}
text.setSpan(clickable, startPos, endPos, flags);
textView.setText(text);
```

Or, if your source is html, you can use `Html.fromHtml("Source text with <a href='whatever'>link</a>")` which parses the HTML and converts links into URLSpan for you.  You then need to replace all `URLSpan` with your own `ClickableSpan` like above. (see [Spanned#getSpans](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Spanned.html#getSpans(int,%20int,%20java.lang.Class%3CT%3E)) and [Spannable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Spannable.html))

This can be tedious.  Thus I created a library [Textoo](https://github.com/bluecabin/Textoo) to simplify the matter.  With Textoo you can achieve the same like:

```
Spanned linksLoggingText = Textoo
    .config("Links: <a href='http://www.google.com'>Google</a>")
    .parseHtml()
    .addLinksHandler(new LinksHandler() {
        @Override
        public boolean onClick(View view, String url) {
            Log.i("MyActivity", "Linking to google...");
            return false; // event not handled.  Continue default processing i.e. link to google
        }
    })
    .apply();
```